# NSTimer invalidation does not work properly

Tags: swift, macos, nstimer

I'm using NSTimer in my project:

```
var clickTimer: Timer?

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    clickTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(close(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

and later I invalidate it in

```
override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    if let timer = self.clickTimer {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

the code inside of `mouseUp` is running but the `close` method of the timer is still running in 2 seconds. Why invalidation does not work?

Comment: Try using `self.clickTimer` during the initialization..

Comment: @0yeoj it did not help as well =/

Comment: In which class are these functions and property implemented?

Comment: is see now., you dont want to redeclare your `clickTimer` so what you want to do is `if (self.clickTimer == nil)
        {
            self.clickTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(close(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }`

Comment: Just a thought though, you are reinitializing the clicktimer multiple times, the previous was successfully invalidated but you accidentally redeclaring a new timer.. hmm..

Comment: @0yeoj yes! It helped me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Should i post my comment as an answer?

Comment: @0yeoj yes, please

Comment: And if you click long, short, long, does the timer fire again?

Comment: @Willeke, I think it will if he will add `self.clickTimer = nil` after `timer.invalidate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now., You dont want to redeclare your `clickTimer` so what you want to do is

```
if (self.clickTimer == nil) { 
    self.clickTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(close(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false) 
}
```

Just a thought though, you are reinitializing the clicktimer multiple times, the previous was successfully invalidated but you accidentally redeclaring a new timer.. hmm..

I also suggest you add `self.clickTimer = nil` after `timer.invalidate()` just to be safe

Comment: So `self.clickTimer` will always be `nil`?

Comment: No, just right after the -invalidate function. if he will set the clickTimer to nil, redeclaration such as `clickTimer = Timer...` will be executed again

Comment: When `if (self.clickTimer == nil)` is executed, will `self.clickTimer ` always be `nil`?

Comment: Hmm yeah, unless mouseDown is called again.

Comment: How do you do two mouseDowns without a mouseUp?

Answer (score 0):

you are invalidate an instance of self.clickTimer , you should invalidate self.clickTimer

```
override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
  if let timer = self.clickTimer {
      self.clickTimer.invalidate()
  }
}
```

---

### Update

i see , you didnt fire the clickTimer ! first if you want to do like this you must fire this variable -> clickTimer.fire()

then when you wanted you should invalidate ,

```
'Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(close(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

automatic runs when you want to declare clickTimer but its not what you want to invalidate !!!

Comment: the same thing happens

Comment: i see , you didnt fire the clickTimer ! first if you want to do like this you must fire this variable -> clickTimer.fire() then when you wanted you should invalidate , Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(close(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false) automatic runs when you want to declare clickTimer but its not what you want to invalidate !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, invalidate it first and than remove the reference.

```
override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    self.clickTimer?.invalidate()
    self.clickTimer = nil
}
```

Comment: it did not help also =/

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when `mouseDown(with:)` is called multiple times, your original timer will be replaced which therefore means you have no reference to invalidate it.

```
var clickTimer: Timer?

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    clickTimer?.invalidate()
    clickTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(close(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    clickTimer?.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

private var clickTimer: NSTimer?

```
func functionname() {
        guard clickTimer == nil else { return }
        clickTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15, target: self, selector: "fetchWallPosts", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

or

```
self. clickTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(yourmethod)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
if (self.clickTimer == nil) { 
self.clickTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(close(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false) 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context?